# WebAPI help page for complex type in URI

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm using [WebAPI help page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/yaohuang1/archive/2012/08/15/introducing-the-asp-net-web-api-help-page-preview.aspx) to provide a documentation.
Documentation is generated fine (from xml comments) except when I use complex model in the uri.
So, I get the following doc

```
GET service/Tst2    No documentation available.
```

for the method:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// description
    /// </summary>
    [HttpGet]
    public string Tst([FromUri] TstModel filter)
    {
        return null;
    }

    public class TstModel
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }
```

for other methods with simple int/string parameters it works as expected. If I remove *[FromUri]* attribute it also works, but then

So the question is: how can I show documentation for such methods? How can I provide documentation for complex types taken from the URI?

Comment: the first part of the problem is solved, the second one is - how to add documentation for such complex class parameters?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regarding your original question about help not being generated for Complex Type decorated with [FromUri] attribute, its a known issue on which we would be working on.

Comment: Has this been fixed now?  I'm running into what looks like the same problem (on Web API 2.x) four years after your comment.

Putting in a model binder doesn't seem to help.  Using a type converter works around the problem, though.

Do you have the bug ID for this?

Answer (score 3):

The reason why it outputted "No documentation available." is because my `TstModel` class was a nested class (defined inside the controller), which made the WebAPI help generate wrong XPath for finding xml-comments.
Moving `TstModel` out of controller helped.

P.S.
The fix in HelpPage code is easy, I just don't know where to report the bug&fix (wrote in NuGet at the moment) :)

It's: `XmlDocumentationProvider.GetTypeName`

line 109: `return type.FullName.Replace("+", "."); //was: return type.FullName`

and line 101:
`string typeName = genericType.FullName.Replace("+", "."); //was: string typeName = genericType.FullName`

Comment: you can report the bug over here: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/workitem/list/basic